# Filter the data of a school to which the user belongs

Tags: laravel-5, php-5.6

I want to display the list of students from a school the user belongs to and not display data from other schools. for that I created two user tables: id , school_id
school table: id, name, address,....
student table: id,school_id,name,address,....
I want to display the students of the school to whom this user belongs
the display is done in browse.blade.php generated by voyageur
how can i make this filter?

the user belongs to a company and can only see data from that school
I have a browse in /views/students that shows students from all schools

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i am using laravel 5.4 and php 5.6.38

Comment: add code of what you have tried (eloquent query or db query)

Comment: I used a browe of voyager

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Student; // Assuming you have a Student model

public function browseStudents()
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    $schoolId = $user->school_id;
    $students = Student::where('school_id', $schoolId)->get();


    return view('students.browse', compact('students'));
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($students as $student)
    <p>{{ $student->name }} - {{ $student->address }}</p>
@endforeach
```